# Using variables from the main file in command files without getting confused with discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

My problem is pretty weird but essential for my discord.js bot. I tried setting up a command handling process, but when a command needs to use a variable used in the config.json file, I need to add it in the command code, and index code every time, and it gets annoying and crammed.

Here's what I mean.

In index.js:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

try {
    client.commands.get(command).execute(message, bot, Discord, prefix, args);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
}  });
```

and for example, here's a command file:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'help',
descriprion: 'displays the help center',
execute(message, bot, Discord, prefix, args) {
    if(!args[1]){
        const helpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('help center')
        .setColor(0x348a58)
        .setAuthor('froggo')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/0RLKc78.jpg?1')
        .setFooter('need more help? use ' + prefix + 'supportserver')
        message.channel.send(helpEmbed);
    }
}
}
```

Do I always need to include in both files (in the execute part) the variables that I need to use, or is there a more efficient way? Because then, in the index file, there would be something like:

```
execute(discord, name, member, prefix , crewmember, supporting, other-link bla bla bla)
```

Comment: Can you explain what `client.commands.get` does?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `client.commands.get`, you can use `require`.

Like this:

```js
require(command).execute(message, bot, Discord, prefix, args)
```

Comment: but i still need to ass all the needed stuff inside the execute command, right=

Answer (score 0):

You also could store your additional variables inside the client itself (`discord` in your case), `message` or anything else.

For example, let's say you need to get the prefix in another command, just before running your command with message as a parameter, do something like :

```
message.prefix = 'yourCoolPrefix';
```

and you will be able to access it inside the command itself ! :)